# Can we connect ECS Instance with RDS instance in Alibaba Cloud?

Tags: alibaba-cloud, alibaba-cloud-ecs, alibaba-cloud-rds

I would like to know that whether it is possible to connect an ECS instance with RDS instance? If yes, then please explain the process or please share some resources to know about the process.

**Thank You!!**

Comment: The documentation is very clear about this https://www.alibabacloud.com/help/doc-detail/127814.htm

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can connect the ECS instance to the RDS instance through the internet by using the public address of the RDS instance.

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean your application on your ECS being able to connect to your RDS? Yes, of cause.
[image]
([Source](https://www.alibabacloud.com/help/doc-detail/26124.htm?spm=a2c63.p38356.b99.81.24132831JP8IX6))

After you [create your RDS](https://www.alibabacloud.com/help/doc-detail/26117.htm?spm=a2c63.p38356.879954.11.4a55439fY3WL2l#concept-wzp-ncf-vdb), you'll have to [configure a whitelist](https://www.alibabacloud.com/help/doc-detail/43185.htm?spm=a2c63.p38356.b99.83.70252831aEiq11) of IPs which can access your RDS, and [create your accounts and databases](https://www.alibabacloud.com/help/doc-detail/87038.htm?spm=a2c63.p38356.b99.84.6090c9achfRyCC) on RDS. Then you can [connect to your RDS](https://www.alibabacloud.com/help/doc-detail/26138.htm?spm=a2c63.p38356.b99.85.24132831JP8IX6) through your ECS by your application or client using the internal endpoints (only within your VPC) provided in the *Basic Information* of your RDS instance. If you need a public endpoint, you can [apply for one](https://www.alibabacloud.com/help/doc-detail/26128.htm?spm=a2c63.p38356.879954.8.10f459a0JIiTYt#concept-nsl-hff-vdb).

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can connect your application on ECS instance to your RDS instance.

You can check this documentation:
https://www.alibabacloud.com/help/product/26090.htm

or specific database:

- [ApsaraDB RDS for MySQL](https://www.alibabacloud.com/help/doc-detail/96047.htm)
- [ApsaraDB RDS for SQL Server](https://www.alibabacloud.com/help/doc-detail/95629.htm)
- [ApsaraDB RDS for PostgreSQL](https://www.alibabacloud.com/help/doc-detail/96715.htm)
- [ApsaraDB RDS for PPAS](https://www.alibabacloud.com/help/doc-detail/96920.htm)
- [ApsaraDB RDS for MariaDB TX](https://www.alibabacloud.com/help/doc-detail/97105.htm)

Comment: Links can go dead - please copy + paste the most important bits into your answer.